# Illustrator default Layer thumbnail

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Can (Adobe) Illustrator set default layer thumbnail size?

Every new document, I need to click "Panel options..." to change layer's thumbnail size bigger.

Answer (score 2):

To me the better way to customise Illustrator is to create a new file, customise inside it everything you always prefer, like and use constantly, then save it as a template (File->Save as Template) and create any new work clicking by File->New From Template choosing this template.

The thumbnails will be preserved by this method.

Answer (score 1):

for me, just modify the default profiles in illustrator.

you can open those profiles and make necessary changes and re-save them again and it will preserve your custom setting in illustrator.
you can finde those profile in the following folder.

C:\Users[your windows profile]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe[Adobe Illustrator 18 Settings][en_AE]\x64\New Document Profiles

please notice that folder between [] may vary.

so do the following:

1. open the default profile folder and duplicate one of your favorite profile. let's say "My Custom RGB.ai"
2. open "My Custom RGB.ai" in illustrator
3. draw anything and delete it. this is important step, because Illustrator will never save your document unless any changes made over the Artboard.
4. set the Layer panel options as you want.
5. save "My Custom RGB.ai"

now for any new document choose from the profile list "My Custom RGB" and all your layer option setting will be preserved.
please note: illustrator will save all your custom setting related to the UI and will never save what you did in your document, that's mean any guidelines or any drawings will not be shown in your new document.
if you want to preserve both UI and documents guide lines .. so you may want to save and open your file using templates methods.
[image: New Document Window]